# Unusual Excel IF Syntax

Tags: microsoft-excel

A colleague has received a spreadsheet from a supplier with the following formula in it.

```
=E10-F10*(H10="Y")-G10*(I10="Y")
```

The supplier explains this field as:

> If H10 and I10 both equal N then J10 equals E10

I am really curious, I have never come across this syntax for an `IF` before and I can't seem to find any documentation regarding it. Is anyone able to explain how it works?

**Example Rows**

```
E       F       G   H   I   J
100,000 2,000   40  N   N   100,000
100,000 2,000   40  Y   Y   97,960
100,000 2,000   40  Y   N   98,000
100,000 2,000   40  N   Y   99,960
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Please note that this particular syntax in some cases might be preferable to a regular formula involving multiple IFs. This syntax basically is equal to 2 string comparisons, 2 multiplications and 2 substractions, compared to 2 string comparisons, 2 if-blocks and 2 substractions when using an IF statement. I'm not sure how Excel works under the hood, but I would imagine that the multiplications have less going on than the IF statements and might even work better on extremely slow devices like older embedded devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the parts of the formula marked `(H10="Y")` and `(I10="Y")`  are either evaluating to either **TRUE** or **FALSE**.  Translated to the spreadsheet this means `TRUE = 1` and `FALSE = 0`.  Mathematically in the equation he is either multiplying by 0 or 1.

So line 1

```
E       F       G   H   I   J
100,000 2,000   40  N   N   100,000
```

`=E10-F10*(H10="N")-G10*(I10="N")`
translates to
`E10-F10*0-G10*0`
which means

```
E10-0-0
100,000-0-0
100,000
```

line 2

```
E       F       G   H   I   J
100,000 2,000   40  Y   Y   97,960
```

`=E11-F11*(H10="Y")-G11*(I11="Y")`
translates to
`=E11-F11*1-G11*1`
which means

```
100,000-2,000-40
97,960
```

In short the logic is saying when H="Y" multiply by 1 (or include this part)
In short the logic is saying when H="N" multiply by 0 (zero out the result)

Same for I

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have accepted this answer as it was the technical explaination I was after.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is exactly equivalent to:

```
=E10-IF(H10="Y",F10,0)-IF(I10="Y",G10,0)
```

because factors like:

```
(H10="Y")
```

will evaluate to either **1** or **0**